# Spacemacs like function overview in Emacs

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs

I previously started using spacemacs, but after a while I wanted to make my own configuration from scratch with a clean install of emacs. I'm trying to get some functionality available in spacemacs, but can't seem to figure out how.

In spacemacs, when you press SPC, C-x, C-c etc. you get a list of all available keycombinations/functions in the mini buffer.

[image]

It is available for both Ivy and Helm, so I'm not sure which package is used for this.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Typically, if you start a chord, you can then press `?` to see the available keys that can follow what you have already typed. The interface is not as pretty, but still helpful.

Answer (score 2):

which-key is the package you need. You can get it from MELPA or the Github repo.

Links:

- [Package on MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/which-key)
- [Github Repo](https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key)